# How to update all documents in collection of Firestore?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I want to change single field in all document of my collection. How I can do this in java ? 
Structure of collection:

```
"Users"
      == SCvm1SHkJqQHQogcsyvrYC9rhgg2 (user)
              - "isPlaying" = false   (field witch I want to change)

      == IOGgfaIF3hjqierH546HeqQHhi30
              - "isPlaying" = true
```

I tried use something like this but it's work

```
 fStore.collection("Users").document().update("isPlaying", false);
```

I made research and found [question about the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51481192/firestore-update-all-documents-in-collections) but that is in JavaScript which I don't understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a document, you must know the full path for that document. If you don't know the full path, you will need to [load each document from the collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection) to determine that path, and then update it.

Something like:

```
db.collection("Users")
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());

                    document.getReference().update("isPlaying", false);
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

This code is mostly copy/paste from the documentation, so I recommend spending some more time there.

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve all documents in a collection using `getDocuments()` and then update each document. The complete code is :

```
//asynchronously retrieve all documents
    ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> future = fStore.collection("Users").get();
    List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = future.get().getDocuments();
    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : documents) {
      document.getReference().update("isPlaying", true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase experts recommend using transaction https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions