# How to bulk edit documents via firestore console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm wondering if there is a way to bulk update documents in firestore via the Firestore console. I'm aware that I am able to do this via code, as shown in answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51481192/5648954) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52165352/how-can-i-update-more-than-500-docs-in-firestore-using-batch), but I'm mainly looking for a way to do this via the Firestore console/UI.

At the moment, I am able to update one document at a time, but is there a way for me to update all documnts (matching a filter for example) at the same time to have the same update?:

[image]

I find that I often want to do this when I'm prototyping, and having to write code just to do a bulk update adds additional time to something I would think would be simple to do via the UI. I'm currently on the free spark plan, so I also can't use cloud-functions, meaning I have to spin up a server to do the bulk update via the admin SDK. Is there a way to bulk update documents via the firestore console or some other UI?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Cloud firestore supports editing [single documents](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/using-console#edit_data) via console. but not in bulk. The only way to edit documents in bulk is either using [**Batch writes**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) or **Transactions**. If it is necessary for you to use console, you can raise feature request [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features)