# How to update each document in the firestore when I click the button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am doing a covid app in react with firestore database. I am new to this firebase. For this app, I have created a collection in firestore named 'VaccinationCentre'. In that I have given 4 fields that are 'State,District,Centrename,NoofDose'.

[image: Collection in firestore with 2 documents]

I have attached an image where I have 2 cards for the 2 documents which I have added in the collection. My aim is to update the 'NoofDose' in each card by decreasing the value by 1 when ever the button 'apply' is clicked.For eg, if the NoofDose is 100 , after I click the button 'apply' it should show as 99 without **manual refresh**.I have tried but I was not able to update each document. I was not able to do that.I have inserted the code for your reference. Kindly help with this.

[image: Output]

```
function SearchVaccinCenter() {
    
    const history = useHistory();
    const auth = getAuth();
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    const db = getFirestore();
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    if (!user) {
        return <Redirect to="/login" />
    }
    function back() {
        history.push("/UserHome")
    }
    async function fetchdata() {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "VaccinationCentre"));
        const mapdata = querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => {
            
            return {
                centername: e.data().Centrename,
                district: e.data().District,
                state: e.data().State,
                noofdose: e.data().NoofDose,
                
            }
        })
        setData(mapdata);
        console.log(mapdata);
        
    }

    function ApplyForVaccination() {
        const database = getFirestore(); // initialize Firestore

        const docRef = doc(database, "VaccinationCentre", "Jtu2QyO1jxmhUl9mKZOc");
        console.log(doc.id);
        const data = {
            NoofDose: 50
        };

        updateDoc(docRef, data)
            .then(response => {
                console.log("Value of an Existing Document Field has been updated");
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error.message);
            })
    }

    return (

        <div style={{height:"600px"}}>
            <div className="continer">
                <nav  className="navbar navbar-light bg-dark">
                    <div  className="container-fluid">
                        <button style={{color:"white",backgroundColor:"grey"}} className="btn btn-outline-secondary" onClick={back}>Back</button>
                        <div className="d-flex">
                            <button style={{color:"white"}} type="button" className="btn btn-white">Hello {user.displayName}</button>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </nav>
                
            </div>
            <div style={{marginTop:"20px"}} className="col-md-12 text-center">
                <button className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" onClick={fetchdata}>Press to search</button>
                {data.map((element, index) => {
                return (
                    <div key={index} style={{width:"500px",margin:"50px 0px 0px 380px"}} className="card border-secondary mb-3">
                        <div style={{backgroundColor:"aliceblue"}}>
                            <h4 className="card-title ms-3"><b>No of Dose : {element.noofdose}</b></h4>
                            <div className="card-body">
                                <h6>State : {element.state}</h6>
                                <h6>District : {element.district}</h6>
                                <h6>Centre Name : {element.centername}</h6>   
                                {console.log(element.state)}
                                <button className="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" onClick={() => ApplyForVaccination()}>Apply</button> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SearchVaccinCenter;
```

Comment: "I was not able to do it" is really hard to help with. I recommend debugging your code locally, and telling us the outcome. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: If you don't know how to increment/decrement a value, have a look at the documentation on the atomic increment/decrement operator: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value

Comment: In the above code , I mentioned specifically the id there to update [refer : initailize firestore in the above code].so the specific document is getting updated. But I want the id for each document to get passed.So, that I can able update whenever I click the 'apply' button[refer the apply button in the code].

Comment: If you're asking how to update all documents in a Firestore collection, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51481192/firestore-update-all-documents-in-collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to update the document based on document id but when you load data with `fetchdata()` function. You are not saving the document id of each document in the `data` state.

I will recommend you to also add id field in your `data` state and use that to update the document as follows:

```
// Load data
async function fetchdata() {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "VaccinationCentre"));
    const mapdata = querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => {
        return {
// add the document ID to the data object so that you can update each document by sending this id
            id: e.id, // ⇐ saving id
            centername: e.data().Centrename,
            district: e.data().District,
            state: e.data().State,
            noofdose: e.data().NoofDose,    
        }
    })
    setData(mapdata);
    console.log(mapdata);    
}
```

And while updating just use that `element.id` and send `element.noofdose` as in your case you also want to decrement the `NoofDose` by 1.

```
//Update Document
function ApplyForVaccination(docId, currentNoOfDose) {
    const database = getFirestore();
// for safety also check if docId and currentNoOfDose is undefined or null
    const docRef = doc(database, "VaccinationCentre", docId);
    const data = {
        NoofDose: currentNoOfDose - 1
    };

    updateDoc(docRef, data)
        .then(response => {
            console.log("Value of an Existing Document Field has been updated");
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.message);
        })
}
```

And then call `ApplyForVaccination()` as follows:

```
<button className="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button" onClick={() => ApplyForVaccination(element.id, element.noofdose)}>Apply</button>
```

In this way you can update the document. But after the update you need to run the `fetchdata()` functions again to reflect the latest data in your UI.

If you want realtime update occur in your UI then use [**`onSnapshot`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#web-version-9)

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful help @RohitKharche .I am getting error while using onSnapshot in this case. So will u please tell me how to use that. Thanks in advance .

Comment: @VaishnaviS Have you tried without onSnapshot and did it work ? For onSnapshot you will need to introduce useEffect. For that it is not possible to explain in this question itself so ask new question about onSnapshot.

Comment: Does the above answer solve your issue ?

Comment: Yes obviously Rohit.

Comment: I am not able to ask questions right now Rohit.

Comment: @VaishnaviS yeah there is a cooldown period for asking answers so you have to wait

Comment: I have asked another question about onsnapshot. Please guide me. Thanks in advance.